# Simplify this Boolean expression: $(BC'+A'D)(AB'+CD')$.

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need to simplify this Boolean expression:
$(BC'+A'D)(AB'+CD')$

I'm unsure what the theorems say about this. But I've tried this, and not sure if this is the right way:
$BC'AB' + BC'CD' + A'DAB' +A'DCD'$ ...and this is ezpz.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a boolean variable $X$, $XX'=0$, since either $X$ or $X'$ must be $0$. This can be used to solve your expanded expression.

Comment: The expression should be 0.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Yes, that is correct. This answer only intends to provide a starting point.

Comment: I looked at it and tried the obvious change X and (A or B) = (X and A) or (X and B) to see what happens, and FALSE or 0 happened :-)